# Open Flow Alex Fajkowski

Tags: coverflow

I am using Open Flow(Cover Flow) implementation of Alex Fajkowski https://github.com/thefaj/OpenFlow. I would like to a text lable under the images, which should update for each view. I still cant make it work. Would anyone be so kind and give me some further hints where exactly and how to implement this?

Best Regards Regen

Answer (score 0):

Well theres a delegate method (selectionDidChange) that gives you the currently selected index. Hook up a textView to your view controller. Then update the textview in the delegate method "selectionDidChange"